# Decompile file .dll

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, dll-injection

dll file and I wanna see the source code but I always not success to see that. I already try with ILSpy, .Net Reflector but not success

this [link my .dll file](https://mega.nz/#!O9lUkKLL!_tR6gmYBOQwEN8JaeVPV8oDPyD0E5O8Y-FBGRKD_8uE)

I hope someone can help me

Comment: I suppose you should contact the vendor you have licensed the software from.

Comment: I'd guess the reason you were given a dll, and not the source code, is because they don't WANT you to see the source.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the DLL was written in C++.  It may have been written in FORTRAN or BASIC or some other language.  So decompiling into C++ source may lose a lot in translation.

Comment: If "seeing the source code" would be of any use to you, you would know how to do it.  If you do not know how to do it, then "seeing the source code" is of no use to you, will not help you with whatever it is that you want to accomplish.  You have not posted a question, you have posted an answer.  Think of what you want to accomplish and ask how to accomplish it.  "Seeing the source code" of a DLL is not the answer to any of your problems.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Even decompiling back to the same original language will lose a lot in translation...

Comment: I have the source code but I just wanna try to open it sir

Comment: and the code written in C++

Comment: Learn reverse engineering and if you already have then disassemble the DLL :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use IDA Pro by Hex-Rays. You will usually not get good C++ out of a binary unless you compiled in debugging information. Prepare to spend a lot of manual labor reversing the code.

If you didn't strip the binaries there is some hope as IDA Pro can produce C-alike code for you to work with. Usually it is very rough though, at least when I used it a couple of years ago.